# What's included in the "Initialization time" in the Symfony2 web profiler?

Tags: symfony

I'm looking at the timeline in the Symfony2 web profiler. The total request time is 800ms and initialization time is 750ms. The detailed breakdown shows all the useful info happening in the 50ms. But what counts towards that 750ms? If it's cache warmup why does it remaining even on subsequent refreshes?

Note: this is dev environment. I'm not performance tuning, I'm just curious why it's such a huge portion of the time profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the code is here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/TimeDataCollector.php#L110

Specifically `This is the time spent until the beginning of the request handling.`