# Symfony2 Slow Initialization Time

Tags: performance, ubuntu, symfony, virtualbox

I have Symfony2 running on an Ubuntu Server 12.04 (64-bit) VM (VirtualBox).  The host is a MacBook pro.  For some reason I am getting really long request times in development mode (app_dev.php).  I know its slower in dev mode, but I'm talking 5-7 seconds per request (sometimes even slower).  On my Mac I get request times of 200ms or so in development mode.

After looking at my timeline in the Symfony2 profiler, I noticed that ~95% of the request time is "initialization time".  What is this?  What are some reasons it could be so slow?

This issue only applies to Symfony2 in dev mode, not any other sites I'm running on the VM, and not even to Symfony2 in production mode.

I saw this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162429/whats-included-in-the-initialization-time-in-the-symfony2-web-profiler), but it doesn't seem to answer my questions.

Comment: depending on your project, 5-7 seconds could be ok, templates and services need to recompile, so when that happens you get this 5 to 10 seconds, it should be fine, the following requests should not take that long to initialise

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out the cause of the problem (and its not Symfony2).  For some reason on the ubuntu VM, the modification times on certain files are incorrect (ie in the future, etc).  When symfony2 checks these times using filemtime() against its registry, it determines that the cache is not longer fresh and it rebuilds the whole thing.  I haven't been able to figure out why it is doing that yet.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. But it doesn't make sense that SF2 'dev' (app_dev.php) environment is working slower than 'prod' (app.php) when they are on the same server. you should figure out what SF2 dev setting is creating the speed issue.

Comment: Symfony2 dev checks for changed files and rebuilds the cache on every request if needed.  Production mode does not.  This is where (most of) the speed difference between the 2 environments comes from.

Comment: @orourkedd I have the same problem with the Symfony2 Initialization time is about 95% of total time. Your comment makes sense. However have you figured out how to fix this?

Comment: @orourkedd, just encountered the same issue on OSX+boot2docker. The problem was that time was not synchronized between host system (OSX) and the docker host (boot2docker).

Answer (score 132):

I had 5-30 sec responses from Symfony2 by default. **Now it's ~500ms** in dev environment.

Then I modified the following things in `php.ini`:

- **set `realpath_cache_size = 4M`** (or more)
- disabled `XDebug` completely (test with `phpinfo`)
- realpath_cache_ttl=7200
- enabled and set `OPcache` (or APC) correctly
- restarted Apache in order to have php.ini reloaded

And voilá, responses went under 2 secs in dev mode!

**Before:** 6779 ms
[image]

**After:** 1587 ms

[image]

Symfony2 reads classes from thousands of files and that's a slow process. When using a small PHP realpath cache, file paths need to be resolved one by one every time a new request is made in the dev environment if they are not in PHP's realpath cache. The realpath cache is too small by default for Symfony2. In prod this is not a problem of course.

### Cache metadata:

Caching the metadata (e.g. mappings) is also very important for further performance boost:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver: apc
                result_cache_driver: apc
```

You need to enable `APCu` for this. It's `APC` without bytecode cache, as `OPCache` already does opcode caching. `OPCache` is built in since PHP 5.5.

### ---- **After:** 467 ms ----

(in prod environment the same response is ~80 ms)

[image]

Please note, this is project uses 30+ bundles and has tens of thousands of lines of code, almost hundred own services, so 0.5s is quite good on a local Windows environment using just a few simple optimizations.

Comment: Setting `realpath_cache_size = 4096k` worked for us. Thank you!

Comment: I guess this is not needed if you have an up to date https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/web/app_dev.php ?  Because as far as i understand the line `$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php.cache'` contains the classes from all those thousands of files (that's why i think changing realpath_cache_size from default value to 4096 had no effect in my case)

Comment: My tests showed that this is not the case. Symfony 2.4 with compiled bootstrap.php.cache still gives good improvement if you set realpath_cache_size higher, just make sure that you set realpath_cache_ttl to some higher number as well, otherwise you'd have big cache which is cleared often

Comment: I also found another issue, realpah_cache_size does not have any effect if open_basedir or safemode is enabled, see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698728/symfony2-very-slow-bootstrap-on-shared-hosting

Comment: It didn't work for me. I think it's just slow running on the VirtualBox vm. I did everything suggested here, and I can't get load times less than 11 seconds. It's better than before I started messing with it, even with just a simple loading of a page that does nothing but render html, it's 11 seconds or slower. It must be the VM, because the same code runs fine on other non-VM linux servers.

Comment: I added a few more things to the original answer to make dev environment even faster

Comment: Do I need to clear APC cache after deploy if I use `metadata_cache_driver: apc`?

Comment: yes, but keep in mind that it usually won't work if you clear the APC/APCu cache from the console because the web server (Apache) and the console run different PHP executables. So it's best to call the 'apc_clear_cache()' through the web server over HTTP

Answer (score 4):

I also needed to disable `xdebug (v2.2.21)` to debug apache2 max timeout loading on my macbook. It was installed using macports:

```
sudo port install php54-xdebug.
```

With xdebug enabled, every page run out max loading time, with a fatal error exceeding max timeout message dispatched. When disabled, everything just loads fine in a reasonable expected time. I came to this using MAMP, no xdebug enabled by default, and apache2 just works fast as usual. I may change for another debugger, that's a pitty, because xdebug worked fine before.

Config:

- MacOSX 10.6.8
- macports 2.1.3
- Apache 2.2.24
- php 5.4

Comment: After some research on symfony2 website, I found in the cookbook some hints to help configure symfony2 for debugging purpose. Disable the bootstrap file and the class caching in app_dev.php helps your debugger be "happier". One main constraint, has to be reverted when debugging session finished. [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/debugging.html)

Comment: I came back after some years and give some enlightenment about why my php installation was not suited to run xdebug correctly. I came to this when I updated my php to version 5.4.42. My phpinfo seems not in sync with my php installation, still didn't I update the required php extensions, and therefore running again into these errors. But cleaning macports and update all outdated/inactive ports including php extensions to the most compatible version with my current php install fix it at last. I use xdebug every day now with symfony2/phpunit without any trouble to generate coverage reports.

Answer (score 4):

We have the same problem.
Here we have 10 second and more for every request.
I see if I remove following lines in bootstrap.php.cache all times return in normal state (298 ms).

```
foreach ($meta as $resource) { 
if (!$resource->isFresh($time)) {
return false;
}
}
```

It's possible that we have wrong modifications times, but we don't know how to fix. Somebody know a solution?

Comment: Tnx for your attention. We use debian.  I can't see a valid solution in your link.

Comment: exactly the same issue as you have and your solution speeded up whole projects from 7 seconds to 900 ms...

Answer (score 2):

As said at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967229/6108843 the reason of such behavior might be Ubuntu VM settings. You should to sync date and time between host and guest OS as explained at https://superuser.com/questions/463106/virtualbox-how-to-sync-host-and-guest-time.

File modification date changes to host's value when you upload file to VM via FTP. So that's why filemtime() returns wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

You can move `APP/var/cache` в `/dev/shm/YourAppName/var/cache`. But it's good to have built container in local files too for IDE autocomplete and code validation. In `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('cache/' . $this->getEnvironment());
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('logs');
}

private function getVarOrShmDir($dir)
{
    $result = dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/' . $dir;

    if (
        in_array($this->environment, ['dev', 'test'], true) &&
        empty($_GET['warmup']) && // to force using real directory add ?warmup=1 to URL
        is_dir($result) && // first time create real directory, later use shm
        file_exists('/bin/mount') && shell_exec('mount | grep vboxsf') // only for VirtualBox
    ) {
        $result = '/dev/shm/' . 'YourAppName' . '/' . $dir . '/' . $this->getEnvironment();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I disabled xdebug and it resulted in a decrease loading time from 17s (yea..) to 0.5s.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems as well with slow page loads in development, which can extremely frustrating when you're tweaking CSS or something similar.

After a bit of digging I found that for me the problem was caused by Assetic which was recompiling all assets on every page load:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment

By disabling the use of the Assetic controller I was able to drastically increase my page load. However, as the link above states, this comes at a cost of regenerating your assets whenever you make a change to them (or set a watch on them).

Answer (score -2):

In app_dev, all the caches and auto loading is starting from scratch and what I found to be most slow in dev is the orm. I shy away from using orm and focus mainly on dbal because of it, although i probably shouldn't. Orm is used quite a bit in sf2. My guess is orm is what's slowing you down most in dev. Look at the difference between your dev config and prod config. However, some tweaks to your dev config can make development much snappier and enjoyable.. Just try and be aware of what your doing. for example, turning off the twig controller and then modifying a lot of templates will be kind of frustrating. Your need to keep clearing your cache. But like you mentioned, its dev only and when its time to go live, symfony will speed up for you.

Comment: I know symfony is slow in dev mode.  I'm not talking about being slow, but being really slow.  Sometimes the VM will serve the requests in 200ms, and then for apparently no reason, will start taking 10 seconds or so.

Comment: ORM is REALLY REALLY slow in Dev.. Try commenting out your ORM settings in Config.yml and testing it out. I don't use any ORM services on my projects. Research ORM pro's and con's. ORM's aren't for everyone.. I do my best to write really clean managers so I can swap out databases or other persisting services.

Comment: The problem is not the ORM here