# How can I make Symfony faster on MAMP?

Tags: symfony, mamp

I am working with MAMP to compile my Symfony App and to load each page I have to wait almost a minute.
The live page on the server is really fast so I guess it must have something to do with MAMP? What can I do?

Comment: It's an answer about xampp but maybe it can help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099061/symfony-on-xampp-is-very-slow-in-development-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have so much errors while loading the pages. You can check the console in your browser inspecter. For example you may embed incorrect link or assets.