# Symfony2 - very slow bootstrap on shared hosting

Tags: performance, symfony

There's a big issue I am facing with now - symfony takes 7-10sec to bootstrap. Some research showed that this is because of tons of file inclusions symfony makes at start.

On my local machine I could fix it by increasing realpath_cache_size setting at php.ini, but on shared hosting this does not work (because open_basedir restriction is in effect and php disables realpath cache in this situation).

Now I am stuck as obviosly application is not usable with such huge bootstrap delay.
Does anyone have this issue.. how can I fix it?

Comment: does this happen only the first time after you clean the cache or on every request? And do you use DEV or PROD enviroment?

Comment: this is on every request, prod environment

Comment: the first thing to check is the DEV env log files. i am using Sf2.0.x and Sf2.3.x on shared hosts and the websites rarely take 1s to load. Do you do any heavy logic on every request?

Comment: I am just using fresh symfony 2.4 package to test. Again, if you read my question again I know where the issue is (open_basedir + realpath_cache issue), I just have no idea how to overcome this at shared hosting

Comment: @PavelDubinin How did you find out the file inclusions Symfony performs? I'd like to check that with our setup too.

Comment: @flu this was basically hacking into bootstrapping process and checking what symfony tries to include in its library code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways do fasten symfony bootstrap.

A few hints:

- Be sure you use the "prod" environment (and production settings: debugging and profiling disabled, cache enabled, less verbose logs),
- Under high QPS, don't use default PHP sessions handler, it uses a file lock on the user's session file, which disallow parralelized queries (it can hurt a lot if you use Ajax a lot),
- Using the filesystem can be quite slow for caching (especially on shared hosting): put the cache directories under a tmpfs mountpoint or override the caching backend in order to use something else than the filesystem (see http://nerdpress.org/2012/07/10/caching-data-in-symfony2).

See the following checklist covering the basics of symfony2 application deployement for production:
http://www.symfony2-checklist.com/

Comment: *Using the filesystem can be quite slow* Please provide a solution or at least a suggestion.

Comment: Usually, I create a tmpfs mountpoint for my cache directories, but you can override the caching backend and use, for instance, memcache.

This article will show you examples of what you can do:
http://nerdpress.org/2012/07/10/caching-data-in-symfony2/

Comment: My problem really is open_basedir (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53263). It does not allow realpath to be cached, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: @MartinRichard : I suggest you to add this note to your answer.

Comment: @PavelDubinin Symfony "packs" its core features in a single "bootstrap" file, are you sure that this feature is enabled?

Do you know where realpath() is called? Is is performed by PHP (because of the open_basedir feature) or by the classloader? In the latter case, you should be able to write a workaround or use an alternative classloader.

Comment: yes, I am aware of bootstrap cache and it is enabled. But as far as I see symfony only caches its core there, not vendors. I think that vendor inclusions is what causes this slowness effect.

Comment: As far as I know, the core and your own "decorated" classes (such as controllers) are cached, so it's not a solution un your case.
Again, can you trace where the realpath() calls happen?

Comment: I made some profiling and found that Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass is what takes most of the time during bootstrap (362 calls).
Internally in makes "include" call, so 362 includes. With open_basedir enabled this is a disaster (Total cumulative time 5600ms on this single function).

Comment: 362 includes seems to be quite a lot to me, but anyway, IMHO, it probably comes from the hosting server (IO issues, misconfiguration or bad architecture, such as files mounted in NFS without cache or something similar). Event without the realpath cache of PHP, I don't see what would make the system take 5,6s to include 360 files. On the other hand, it bugs me that you said you had to increase the realpath_cache_size on your own computer. I'll try to reproduce on my own computer and on a true shared hosting.

Comment: yes, I just enable open_basedir and it becomes slow for me on local machine. It is fast again when I disable it (if realpath cache setting is high enough). And it's not just symfony, I have same effect on other software using alot of includes

Comment: @MartinRichard, did you try to reproduce it? Please share your findings

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce with a fresh installation of symfony 2.4, php 5.5.9 (xdebug activated or deactivated) on my computer. Sorry.

Comment: Same results (~215ms) on a standard shared hosting with open_basedire restriction in effect.

Comment: Could you try with php 5.3.3 please?

Comment: Same results with php 5.3.3, except for the first time (~1.1sec instead of ~200ms). It is probably because Apache needed to restart and spawn the fastcgi processes though.

Comment: ummm.. my hosting uses mod_cgi and not fastcgi, could it be the reason?

Comment: I don't know, I don't see why it would be the reason, but maybe. Do you also use mod_cgi on your computer? If no, cgi is probably not to blame, else try with mod_fcgi or mod_php.