# Performance issues with Symfony2 and Azure Websites

Tags: php, windows, symfony, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure Websites, and trying to deploy an existing Symfony2.3 app.
Everything seems to work in my app, except for the fact that I have HUGE performance issues that don't exist when I run my app locally or on a linux-based server.

For instance, the login_check call (fosub URL that authenticates a user when logging in), takes up to 10 seconds to redirect to the next URL.

APC is enabled and I don't have any specific errors showing up.

Did anyone encounter a problem similar to mine and how can I improve these terrible perfs ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [Symfony2 Slow Initialization Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905404/symfony2-slow-initialization-time/17914570#17914570)
In `.user.ini` I added:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
realpath_cache_size = 4096k
realpath_cache_ttl=7200
```

Now symfony response is 10 times faster.