# Symfony2 site slow

Tags: symfony, caching, optimization

My Symfony 2 website is slow (+10 seconds for simple page), how can I find the problem?

My APC configuration is:
[image]

[image]

I use Vagrant Box on a Macbook Air 8go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow vagrant box, how to improve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729859/slow-vagrant-box-how-to-improve-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vagrant there is problem with VirtualBox filesyste  (it is slow) .

1. Run NFS  Server  and change sharefs (in vagrant config) to NFS. I  can tell how to do this on win/linux,  but not on mac
2. Cache - move  to folder that is outside share (for example `~/app/cache`) - you need to change cache dir in `AppKernel` 
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir
3. Move  vendors outside  share (for example `~/app/cache`)  - neet to change paht in composer.json
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-vendor-directory